# SQL Server Error - HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge 200MB .SQL file. When I try to open this in SQL server management studio 2008, I get the error -Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

What could the reason be and how to fix it ? Is this caused due to big files ? It does not happen when I open a 2-3 KB file.

Comment: What in the name of... do you have in a 200MB sql file?  If it's a file full of inserts, might I suggest an alternative way to get your data in like BCP?

Comment: @squillman - Can BCP execute my big SQL file ?

Comment: @squillman - another SO member suggested this link. Looks like I am not alone in this - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=170529

Comment: Yes, it can.  But you have to have your data in a delimited format instead of crafted in a bunch of inserts.  Use BCP, or BULK INSERT, or the Import Data function in Magement Studio (right-click the db, choose Tasks -> Import Data).